# Converting RTF file having images to HTML

Tags: html, vb.net, rtf, windows

I am using Windows Application to develop my project. There is one case, in which i need to convert RTF file to HTML and printing it. In the RTF file containing images also. In simple i can convert RTF to HTML. But images cant convert. it not there in the HTML file.

So can anyone give some idea regarding same that how can i do convert RTF file data including Images to HTML file?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML you can embed an image as Base64 encoded. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388264/jeditorpane-with-inline-image), with a `data:` URL. How the binary bytes can easily be converted to Base64 ASCII I do not know.