# HTML5 using src using raw binary data

Tags: java, html, audio, binary, jstl

Let's say I am storing an audio file in the database and later on I would want to use that BLOB or binary in my application.

```
<audio src ="${sessionScope.user.music}">
```

Where `${sessionScope.user.music}` returns a binary data that has been retrieve from the database.

would it be possible to load an audio file in an audio tag, using binary data instead of a uri? or path?

Comment: Let's say that. But what's your question ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew looks I forgot to place the last statement, I have updated it.

Comment: Why cannot you just use url like `src="/user/music"` and have that URL respond with the audio file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit like inline images:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/
f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67
QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g7
7ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7"
    width="16" height="14" alt="embedded folder icon">
```

Where this works for `<img>`, I am far from sure that `data:audio/mp3;base64, ...` (or `audio/ogg`) would work. It is not in my HTML5 reference.

For the encoding, see [JEditorPane with inline Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388264/jeditorpane-with-inline-image).

Comment: @HarloHolmes, I love that. Firefox and IE?

Answer (score 1):

i was in need to inline large amounts (some MB) of binary data for threejs 3D display.

This is what i came up with:

1. write the 8bit binary data into a png file
2. base64 encode the resulting run-length compressed png file
3. use `<img src="data:image/png;base64,....">` to include that into the html5 file
4. create a hidden canvas of appropriate dimension and use context.drawImage and context.getImageData to extract the binary data which is finally stored in an Uint8ClampedArray
5. calculate the needed Float32Array(s) for threejs from that Uint8ClampedArray

I don't know if this works to provide binary music data also, but the question wasn't mentioning music data and it might be helpful for others who stranded here like me looking for general solutions to include binary data into HTML5 :-)

Comment: I am in the same situation, how about the size, I read base64 increase the size

Comment: I made a small javascript library that does exactly that: https://github.com/lovasoa/bin2png

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert your binary data to string using javascript.. See the [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195865/javascript-html-converting-byte-array-to-string)

Comment: why would I need to convert that raw binary data into string?

Comment: beacause HTML does not know binary... you have to provide it in a string

Comment: yup.. it will interpret it.... many of the flash files, videos and other media objects are placed in the form of strings.. actually this string is a Base64 format.. have look on this link... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: if you find that this answer solves your problem then please mark it is answer