# Adding same component to JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextpane, jcomponent

I am setting up a JTextPane with chat like messages. I wanted to represent individual usernames as JLabel's. For an individual user, I wanted to use the identical JLabel object, so that any changes to that JLabel would propagate through all views of them in the same JTextPane.  However, what I have found is that if the same object is inserted (insertComponent(...)), that the JTextPane erases the earlier one from whatever position it was at, and inserts at the current caret position. The first way around this would be to have individual JLabels for each and every username, but this could eventually lead to the creation of thousands of JLabels in the JTextPane.

I'm looking for any suggestions on a better way of going about this. The documentation does not cover this behavior it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any component has a parent component field, so evidently it can only be put in a view hierarchy once.

If you use a content type of the JTextPane styled text, like "text/html" you can insert images too. There is a [swing demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/) with Alice in Wonderland providing low level image objects. In HTML one could add a `<img src='...'>` where the `src` either is a `file:...` or maybe some own protocol to get the image from the classpath (`res:`, `resource:` or `classpath:`). To write a protocol handler is not difficult, just a bit baroque.

Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388264/jeditorpane-with-inline-image) suffices, which answers "JEditorPane with inline image."

Comment: Thanks, I had read the parent component inclusion in the docs and had not understood it, now I do!  If I were to have the the individual entries become fully html, one feature that I would lose would be changing the username on the fly and having them update in the text pane (by a JLabel.setText() call). Is it possible to update html within a text pane as though it had a full DOM behind it?  i.e. if I wrapped the entry in a <div> and then updated the contents of the div outside of the text pane via some DOM mechanism.  I suppose I could edit the StyledDocument directly.

Comment: Simplest would be to do a string replace (div with id="..."). But yes, Styled document has paragraph elements.

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) `Each GUI component can be contained only once.` because of you can only to create a new `JLabel` for each username.

Or you can use a `JTextArea` for your chat board, and add messages as a new lines of decorated name and text ot user.