# JEditorPane with inline image from jar file

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I have a JEditorPane which shows HTML content with images.
I found this article: [JEditorPane with inline image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388264/jeditorpane-with-inline-image).
In this article is mentioned to use a protocol handler "resource:" for class path resources.

I tried this and got it working, when I run the application from Eclipse.
But when I run it with a generated JAR file I'm not able to read the image out of the JAR file.

This is my version of the connection class:

```
public class ResourceConnection extends URLConnection {
    protected ResourceConnection(URL url) {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
        connected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        String filename = url.getFile();
        URL resourceURL = ResourceConnection.class.getResource(filename);
        String resourcePath = resourceURL.toString();

        Path path = null;
        if (resourcePath.startsWith("file:")) {
            resourcePath = resourcePath.substring(5);
            path = Paths.get(resourcePath);
        } else if (resourcePath.startsWith("jar:")) {
            // TODO path to image in jar file
        }

        if (path != null) {
          byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
          return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        } else {
          return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it from Eclipse, the `resourcePath` looks like `file:/path/to/my/project/bin/path/to/image.png`. From this I have to remove the `file:` and the image will be shown.

When I run it with a JAR file, the `resourcePath` looks like `jar:file:/path/to/the/jarfile.jar!/path/to/image.png`. I don't how I have to manipulate the path so that `Files.readAllBytes` can read it. I tried the following:

- without manipulation
- removed `jar:`
- removed `jar:file:`
- converted `resourceURL` to an `URI` and used that with `Paths.get`. This resulted with an `java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException`.

The interessting thing is, when I create an `ImageIcon` with `resourceURL` the image is loaded (`getIconWidth()` and `getIconHeight()` return the correct values).

**Edit**:

The tag in the HTML source looks like `<img src="resource:/path/to/image.png">`.

**Edit**:

The answer of Andrew Thompson gave me the idea to use a `FileInputStream`.

```
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    try {
        String filename = url.getFile();
        URL resourceURL = ResourceConnection.class.getResource(filename);
        return new FileInputStream(new File(resourceURL.toURI()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This again works fine from Eclipse but with the JAR file I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical`. Probably because the URL begins with `jar:file:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally working.

```
public class ResourceConnection extends URLConnection {
    protected ResourceConnection(URL url) {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
        connected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return ResourceConnection.class.getResource(url.getFile()).openConnection().getInputStream();
    }
}
```

Thanks to Andrew Thompson for the idea to work with streams.